How does hot reload works in Flutter?
I am developing a library that has a run function that runs an entire app boilerplate with lots of configuration parameters such as LoginPageColor
How to perform hot reload in way to update the app when I change the color ?
This does not work.
void main() {
  run(loginPageColor: Colors.red); // change this
}
void run({required Color loginPageColor}) {
  runApp(MyApp(loginPageColor: loginPageColor));
}
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final Color loginPageColor;

  const MyApp({Key? key, required this.loginPageColor}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: LoginPage(color: loginPageColor),
    );
  }
}

class LoginPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final Color color;

  const LoginPage({Key? key, required this.color}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: color,
      body: Center(
        child: Text('Login Page'),
      ),
    );
  }
}

I read somewhere hot reload works with isolate, so I made the configuration top-level function which is an UGLY SOLUTION  but it works. Is there a more elegant way to make hot reload works without using this top-level and getter approach ?
MaterialColor getColor (){
  return Colors.pink; // change this to Red
}
void main() {
  run(loginPageColor: getColor);
}

void run({required Color Function() loginPageColor}) {
  runApp(MyApp(loginPageColor: loginPageColor));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final Color Function() loginPageColor;

  const MyApp({Key? key, required this.loginPageColor}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: LoginPage(color: loginPageColor()),
    );
  }
}

class LoginPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final Color color;

  const LoginPage({Key? key, required this.color}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: color,
      body: Center(
        child: Text('Login Page'),
      ),
    );
  }
}

NOTE: It is ugly because I don't want to write a disclaimer in the package description that the configuration should be a "TOP-LEVEL" function otherwise it won't work with hot reload. Unless this is a Dart  limitation, but I don't believe so because Flutter Widgets are not top level  but they work with hot reload.
Is there a good official source that explains deeply how the hot reload works in Dart ?. Most source just explains how to use it with widget but I couldn't find a source that explains how to use it beyond that.

In basic terms , if you do hot reload , the build() is getting re-build, preserving the previous paths and states . Please note , the initState() will not reset , you need to run to do so or navigate back to this page.
